# Getting a view controller back from beneath a view

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a view controller vc1. This vc1 has a button. Upon tapping the button, I have programmed it in such a way that it creates a view and loads it. I am performing some animations on the view. Once those are finished, I want to display whatever I have in the VC1 back. Doing a

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

removes the view, but it remains as a black, blank screen. I want to display things on my VC1. How do I call back vc1 after removing the view that is sitting on top of  it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `removeFromSuperview` on the second view, not your original view like the code above.

Comment: So this gives me back the view conroller on which the view is nested?

Comment: How are you presenting the second view?

Comment: It is actually one view. to make my question clear, i have a view controller upon which, i m programmatically creating my view and putting things on it. I want this view to go away and i want to display the view controller that holds this view. I created a view like this: @property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *view;( in the .h file). In the .m file,  self.view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 200, 20, 20)];
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];